# Reseting the form when usering the jquery validations plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate, reset

I have a simple form like below that I have added the jQuery validations plugin onto ([http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/ValidatioP)). I have this form in a modal popup window so if there are errors and the user closes the window when they open it again the form still has the errors. In my popup close callback I tried calling resetForm() but it says the method doesn't exist.

Form HTML:

```
 <form class="validations" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
   <p>
     <label for="name">Name</label>
     <em>*</em><input id="name" name="name" size="25" class="required" minlength="2" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
     <em>*</em><input id="email" name="email" size="25"  class="required email" />
   </p>
 </form>
```

Popup Close Callback:

```
function(){
  $(this).find('form.validations').resetForm();
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I couldn't vote for you John, but your answer was nicest! I did as described and it worked for me. As a comment, I observed that there is a "$.validator" in jQuery, but this hasn't the resetForm() method. And the validate doesn't return a "validator". The prove is that the returned object doesn't have the method that "$.validator" has. I find this a little bit strange, but this is probably the price of working at higher level of jQuery (instead of js).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`resetForm` is part of the object returned by the validate method, not the form. Example:

```
var validate = $('#commentForm').validate({ ... });
// Later...
validate.resetForm();
// Or if variable scope is in the way...
$('#commentForm').data('validator').resetForm();
```

The validation plugin stores a reference to the validation object in the form's data store.

Comment: What do you mean "variable scope is in the way", can't you get rid of variable and just do `$('#commentForm').validate().resetForm()`? Note that `.validate()` will just return `.data('validator')` if validator has already been initialized.

Answer (score 1):

If it really is a short form with just a few elements, you could simply reset them by hand when the close button on the modal window is clicked, like so:

`$("input[name='formelementName']").val("");`