# Jquery validation not working after clearing a form

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-validate

I have applied validation through JQuery Validation Plugin on my page. The validation works fine but once the `Clear` button is hit to clear out all the fields on the form, and then the save button is clicked again, the validation doesn't fire and the form gets submitted. I have called the following javascript function on click of `Clear` button to clear out all the form fields :-

```
function ResetForm() {
            jQuery(':input', '#form1')
                .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
                .val('')
                .removeAttr('checked')
                .removeAttr('selected');
            return false;
        }
```

The `Clear` button is on a ChildPage and `ResetForm` function is on the MasterPage. Anybody have any guess why its getting submitted after clearing the fields ?

Comment: I think your clearing the form aswell as its within your selector, try `.not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden','form')` so that the `val('')` does not effect it, and change your selection to `jQuery('input', '#form1')`

Comment: No, this is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the error was something else, the code provided by `RobertPitt` is correct for clearing of form fields and my code was also correct for clearing of form fields. But the problem is that, on the `clear` button I had applied a `class="cancel"` so that the form should not get submitted because it was an `aspx:button`.

But according to what is written in JQuery docs, clicking of a button whose class is `cancel` should skip the validation, but after that if I click on a normal `submit` button validation should fire which was not firing in my case.

I just removed the `cancel` class and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

input is an element and not a attribute or a pseudo selectable, the main issue I see in your code is the `:` within the `:input`

Try changing to `jQuery('#form1 input')` to fetch the list of inputs

Also change the `not()` command to select filter the inputs by type

```
.not('[type="button"], [type="submit"], [type="reset"], [type="hidden"]')
```

also as for `:hidden` there's several factors you should know about this.

- They have a CSS display value of none.
- They are form elements with type="hidden".
- Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
- An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

---

In light of your comment please try this tested version:

```
function resetForm()
{
    $("#form1").find(':input').each(function()
    {
        var jelem = $(this);
        switch(this.type)
        {
            case 'password':
            case 'select-multiple':
            case 'select-one':
            case 'text':
            case 'textarea':
                jelem.val('');
                break;
            case 'checkbox':
            case 'radio':
                jelem.attr('checked',false);
        }
    });
}
```

@source: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-clear-form/

Another way to do this is to create a hidden input in your form but set the type as `reset` like so:

```
<input type="reset" style="display:none" />
```

and then do:

```
function resetForm()
{
    $("#form1[type='reset']").click();
}
```

Comment: `jQuery('#form1 input').not('[type="button"], [type="submit"], [type="reset"], [type="hidden"]').val();` - same behavior with this too, clearing out the fields but after clearing if I click on save, the validations again do not fire and form gets submitted and I get errors on the server side.

Comment: Updated with alternative solutions.

Comment: also the your last test the val method should contain an empty string as your returning the values `.val('')`

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

[Reseting the form when usering the jquery validations plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060447/reseting-the-form-when-usering-the-jquery-validations-plugin)

Comment: This `Reset` is not the Reset I am talking about. I am talking about clearing the values of the form fields, not the errors that occurred on firing of validator.